# Signal path between nodes in a MoCA network

Tags: signal, coax, signal-theory

I'm trying to understand how signals propagate between nodes in a MoCA (Multimedia over Coax Alliance) network.  For example, in a typical but simple network, one has a coax input from a service provider that feeds into a coax splitter.  The outputs from the splitter will go to MoCA-enabled devices in the house.  Let's say to be specific a primary router and a WiFi extender.  In such a network the edge devices - the router and the extender in our example - are able to communicate with each other as if they were a local Ethernet network.

(In a real application, the signal may be split in more than two branches and a series of two splitters is allowed.)

At the component level, however, I do not understand how a signal can pass between the edge devices because a well-designed splitter will provide isolation between the output ports.  A message from the router to the extender has to travel down the coax and into an "output" port on the splitter.  It seems from there it should go back out the "input" port (in combination with any signal concurrently coming from the other output port) but should not be able to jump to the other output port and reach the extender with enough strength to carry data.  I considered the possibility that the signal reflects off of something on the provider-side of the splitter and travels back through it the other way to reach the edge, but I cannot see what might cause that.

Being slightly more quantitative, I'm seeing numbers in the range 20-40 dB for isolation on splitters and, reading the diagnostics on devices on my own network, I'm seeing signal strengths of similar magnitude.  That makes me think that the isolation is significant.

Obviously, something about this reasoning is wrong, because the system works and in practice the extender will receive the message.  So the question is what is the physical path for the message between edge devices and/or how does it overcome the isolation in the splitter?

Comment: There's no reason why a "splitter" can't be designed in different ways.

Comment: That's true, but, in this case, we're dealing with readily off-the-shelf coax splitters not any type of special component for this network. @Andyaka  What I described seems to typical design in that case.

Comment: Short answer: there's nothing wrong with 40 dB link loss. Your Wi-Fi's working at 100 dB, and cell phone's happily chugging away at 120 dB loss.